# Dynamically creating subviews of similar type

Tags: iphone, uiview

[image: Screen Shot of what im not trying to do]

My code for above view is:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


    float yh = 0;
    while (yh<200) {

        //UIView
        CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, yh, 320, 30);
        UIView *myFirstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
        myFirstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];


        //IUILabel in UIView
        CGRect mylblFrame = CGRectMake(5, yh, 60, 15);
        UILabel *lblsize = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:mylblFrame];
        lblsize.text = @"Hello";
        [myFirstView addSubview:lblsize];

        CGRect mylbl_hi = CGRectMake(80, yh, 60, 15);
        UILabel *lbl_hi = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:mylbl_hi];
        lbl_hi.text = @"Hii";
        [myFirstView addSubview:lbl_hi];


        [self.view addSubview:myFirstView];
        [lbl_hi release];
         [lblsize release];
        [myFirstView release];


        yh=yh+40;


}
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
  }
```

I can't understand reason of it being like this...i wanted labels to be attached with my subviews of orange color...this may be odd day for me to understand what's wrong with my code...if any of you can tell me where i ma doing wrong would be great to me. This is my first time creating view programmatically..so please excuse me if all this is silly question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside each view the coordinate at the top left corner is 0,0.

your code would work as you expected if you would add your labels to the same view you've added the orange bars.

your code should work when you change yh in your label rects to 0.